# Worksheet_Deactivate() Cannot Use Active Sheet functions

Tags: excel, worksheet

I have 50 datasheets in the project, and nobody remembers to run the save macro when going to another sheet.  The bright idea is to use a private sub Worksheet_Deactivate to do the necessary calculations when they select another worksheet.  In addition to the 50 datasheets, there are two more worksheets in the workbook for which the calculation must not run.  It would be nice if the sub could be put in "Worksheets" rather than replicated 50 times in individual worksheets, but the two other worksheets need to be excluded from processing.

Problem is, the sub defaults to the deactivating worksheet (such as an unqualified "Range.Value =" in the macro code), but the active worksheet is now the worksheet being navigated TO.  So any ActiveXXXXX statement directs to the wrong worksheet.  Worksheet.Name is disallowed.

Datasheets are numbered 1 to 50.  What is needed is a statement early in the deactivate sub similar to

If DeactivatingWorksheet(X) = "BasicInfo" Or "Constants" Then GoTo EndSub
where X is the value of the deactivating worksheet.  Of course, X is known only to Excel at the moment of processing.

I can't seem to figure out how to refer to the deactivating worksheet in the macro's IF statement.  Any ideas?

Comment: It would help if you indicate what type of spreadsheet this is. For example if this is an Excel spreadsheet, edit your question to include the Excel tag.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think.  Yes, this is an Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal sh as Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838589.aspx) instead of [`Worksheet_Deactivate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197183.aspx). The Workbook-level event supplies the name of the sheet being departed, even though in both cases the `ActiveSheet` has already changed when when event fires. Use `sh` just like a worksheet variable - `sh.Name`, `sh.ProtectionMode`, etc.

Now you don't need 50 subs; just one. Another thing that this allows is, you can "abort" the change to the now `ActiveSheet` by `sh.Activate` to the old one (but turn off events or you'll have a lovely infinite loop).

`Me` also gives the old sheetname and works for the worksheet event, if you still want to go that way. `Me` is the old one, `ActiveSheet` is the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Worksheet_Deactivate` and this calls a subroutine in a seperate module, you can pass the name of the deactivating worksheet to the subroutine.

For instance, if your subroutine is something like:

```
Sub test()
    ActiveSheet.Range("whatever") = "something"
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

And you call it from the worksheet like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Module1.test()
End Sub
```

You can add a parameter to the subroutine to take the worksheet name, and add a test:

```
Sub test(worksheetname as string)
    If worksheetname <> "dontsavethistab" then
        ActiveSheet.Range("whatever") = "something"

        'or... you could also do:
        Sheets(worksheetName).Range("Whatever") = "something"

        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
End Sub
```

And call it from your Worksheet_Deactivate event like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Module1.test (Me.Name)
End Sub
```

If you wanted to get a little cleaner, instead of the worksheet name you could pass the worksheet object:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Module1.test(Me)
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub test(ws as worksheet)
    If ws.name <> "dontsavethistab" then
        ws.Range("Whatever") = "something"    
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
End Sub
```

This way you have the entire worksheet object to do with as you please in your subroutine.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but it didn't work.  The Worksheet_Deactivate() seems to be some kind of universe where simple things (like Range("A2").Select) errors out.  In this case the If statements error out with a "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set".  The "Activesheet" statement in your first example wrote to the forwarding sheet, not the deactivating sheet.

Comment: That's a very good reason to not use activesheet. It's a much better practice to be explicit about the sheet you want. The second example I gave would be much better all around. I'm not sure what you mean by `Range("A2").Select` erroring out. First, do you actually need `.Select`? Second, you specify a `Range()` but you don't tell excel which worksheet. It will just work with whatever worksheet is the `activesheet`, which we've already shown is a bad idea. Try getting more explicit with your code and you'll probably find a few of these errors go away on their own.

Comment: Understood, but I can't be specific because I want to put this as a Worksheets module, not replicate it 50 times in each data worksheet. I don't know the worksheet name, and any Activesheet returns the forwarding module, not the deactivating module. Range().Value = X works, but Range().Select bombs out.  However, ws.Range().Select does work. Your "IF" functions bomb out (or the worksheet reference bombs out), which is what I need to function to exclude the two sheets that must be unaffected.  The next thing I need is to determine if the deactivating sheet is one of the two excluded sheets.

Comment: Sorry for the very late response... Are you using the `Workbook_SheetDeactivate` event in the `ThisWorkbook()` code?