# Clearing selection when leaving sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to clear the selection on sheet "sheet2" when leaving the sheet. (e.g reset to cell A1)

I tried:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

And:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

But this is not working. (first one selects A1 on the current sheet, and the second one gives an error)

The reason why I want this, is because a macro has selected an object (Shape form control) that is protected (locked text). When a user leaves and returns to the sheet, while this object is still selected an error occurs:

> You cannot use this command on a protected sheet. To use this command... etc

The reason why a macro selected the object in the first place, is because the user clicked on a hyperlink that would highlight this object. (I can't think of a different way then 'select' to highlight a shape form control)

**Possible solution:**
The only other method I can think of is have a Sub "Worksheet_Deactivate()" that first activates sheet "Sheet2" clears the selection to A1 and then returns to the sheet the user has initially clicked on when leaving the sheet..... but this feels cumbersome.

Is there another solution/method? any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work so long as you are not working in a shared workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
If Sh.Name = "Sheet2" Then Sh.Protect
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
If Sh.Name = "Sheet2" Then Sh.Unprotect
End Sub
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41015756/2557128), you can use the `Workbook_SheetDeactivate` event and get a `WorkSheet` object that you can then change the selection on without switching the active sheet.

Further reading seems to indicate `Me` will contain the sheet that has just been deactivated in the `Worksheet_Deactivate` handler, so you could also use that.

Comment: `Me` always refers to the current run-time instance of the class module you're looking at. If that's a specific worksheet's code-behind, `Me` always refers to *that* worksheet. Always - no ifs, no buts.

Comment: Ah - `Worksheet_Deactivate` is a sheet specific event, so that is why it is the previous sheet after a sheet change.

Comment: I tried to use `me` in `WorkBook_SheetDeactivate` and `WorkSheet_Deactivate`. `me.ActiveSheet` in `WorkBook_SheetDeactivate` refers to the **current** sheet, whereas `me`in `WorkSheet_Deactivate` refers to the **previous** sheet.
I tried `me.Range("A1").Select` but unfortunately this gave me the same 4001 error as `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Select` did.
Maybe there is still a workaround, but because matt2103's answer worked out, I will continue with that approach.