# How to interrupt Worksheet Deactivate?

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel 365 on Windows 10. Edited for clarity.

My workbook has several "Payday" sheets, and a sub called `SavePayday` which copies values from that sheet to another.

I want to trigger `SavePayday` when the user goes from a Payday sheet to another tab. I can do that by calling it in the `Workbook_SheetDeactivate` area.

But I want to give the user the option of cancelling the move: by not running `SavePayday` and staying on Payday. A simple "Are you sure you want to save this? Yes/No" message box.

Here on SO, someone mentioned that we could "interrupt" `Workbook_SheetDeactivate` before the user actually leaves the sheet. It was mentioned briefly in a comment, without fully being explained.

How can I trigger that message box so that the user can still see the Payday sheet, and if the answer is no, stay on the sheet instead of switching?

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32261280/445425)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim ws: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    sh.Activate
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If MsgBox("Are you sure ?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ws.Activate
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work. When I pressed "No",, it still proceeded to the new sheet, not staying on Payday. I modified your code, and since it seems to work, I took the liberty of editing your answer.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, try `Me.Activate`. Which version of Excel and OS ? Ypu can probable just disable/enable events at start and end.

Comment: `Me.Activate` didn't work, and `Me.Name` gives me the name of workbook, not either sheet

Comment: @Shawn did you put code on the workbook event `Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal sh as Object)` ? I thought you only wanted it on the Payday sheet deactivate event ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I wanted this to work from various sheets similar to Payday, but for some reason I didn't think that was important to mention. Silly me for rushing. Will edit the question.